# Using SageMath as a python library

Tags: python, sage

Is it possible to import the SageMath functions inside a python session?

What I wish to do, from a user perspective is something like this:

```
>>> import sage
>>> sage.kronecker_symbol(3,5)  # ...or any other sage root functions
```

instead of accessing `kronecker_symbol(3,5)` from a sagemath session.
If possible, it would be very handy, as would allow embedding all the functionalities of SageMath within the python world.

Comment: Provide details: operating system, Python version...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Importing SageMath functions in a Python session

There are several ways to achieve that.

#### SageMath from the operating system's package manager

Some operating systems have Sage packaged natively,
for example Arch Linux, Debian, Fedora, Gentoo, NixOS,
and their derivatives (Linux Mint, Manjaro, Ubuntu...).

See the dedicated "Distribution" page on the Sage wiki:

- [SageMath distribution and packaging](https://wiki.sagemath.org/Distribution)

If using one of those, use the package manager
to install `sage` or `sagemath` and then the
Sage library will be installed on the system's
Python, and in that Python it will become possible
to do things like

```
>>> from sage.arith.misc import kronecker
>>> kronecker(3, 5)
-1
```

Another option is to use a cross-platform package manager
such as Conda, Guix and Nix. These should work on most
Linux distributions and macOS. Yet another option would be
to run a Docker container.

I will detail the Conda case below.

#### SageMath with Conda

Install Sage with Conda and you will get that.

Instructions are here:

- [SageMath installation: install from conda-forge](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/conda.html)

and start by installing a Conda distribution, either
Miniconda, Minimamba or Anaconda, and then creating a
`sage` conda environment.

Once a `sage` conda environment is installed, activate it:

```
conda activate sage
```

With that `sage` conda environment active, run

```
python
```

and importing the `sage` module or importing functions
such as `kronecker` from that module should work.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! Is there a way to install it on the python interpreter in a virtualenvironment (and without using conda)?

Comment: @SeF Making the SageMath library a pip-installable package (depending on having installed all the required components) is the object of Sage Trac ticket 21507: https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/21507 -- achieving that sooner might be possible depending on the operating system.

Comment: Importing sage/sagemath into VS Code won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Evaggelos Manousakis you need to set up VS Code to use the same Python your Sage is based on.

Comment: I have been trying for weeks to make it work but I didn't try this one. I will do my best and let you know. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

This is a complementary answer for those who fail to use some SageMath function that is not compatible with Python syntax.

For example;

```py
from sage.all import *

F = GF(2)
R.<x> = k[]
```

This will give an error on `R.<x> = k[]` since it is not a valid Python syntax. So how to solve this issue?

SageMath parses the SageMath syntax then use Python. One needs to use [preparse](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/repl/sage/repl/preparse.html) to see the actual command.

```
sage: preparse('R.<x> = k[]')
"R = k['x']; (x,) = R._first_ngens(1)"
```

So replace the line, done!

```py
from sage.all import *

F = GF(2)
R = k['x']; (x,) = R._first_ngens(1)
```

Unfortunately one must use SageMath to identify these.

Answer (score -5):

1/ pip install sage 
2/ from sage import *

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm not sure what I downloaded, but that doesn't look like sagemath.