# How to use sagemath on python?

Tags: python, sage

I would like to use cubegroup of sagemath. I did as follows.

```
python -m pip install sagemath
```

and then

```
import sagemath.cubegroup;
```

in python script. But I got the following error.

```
ImportError: No module named cubegroup
```

I tried both python2 and python3 but neither worked.
I also tried sage instead of sagemath, but didn't work either.

How can I use sagemath and cubegroup on python?

Comment: First, is Sage installed on your system? If not, the module won't work. If it is, try `from sagemath import cubegroup`.

Comment: I installed the following binary, but still it doesn't work. https://github.com/sagemath/sage-windows/releases/download/0.6.2-9.2/SageMath-9.2-Installer-v0.6.2.exe

Comment: Which OS are you using? Does sudo apt install sagemath work?

Comment: @smitty_werbenjagermanjensen Windows 10, with binaries installed from http://www-ftp.lip6.fr/pub/math/sagemath/index.html

Comment: @desura i used this when installing sagemath on linux im thinking it may help you for installing on windows if not i can take a closer look later https://doc.sagemath.org/pdf/en/installation/installation.pdf

Comment: @smitty_werbenjagermanjensen For Windows, this document basically tells you to install some pre-built binaries, which I did. The problem is not the installation of SageMath but how to make it work with some editor like PyCharm.

Comment: @Desura sounds like your looking for this https://ask.sagemath.org/question/39742/make-pycharm-recognise-the-sage-python-interpreter/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using SageMath as a python library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61408795/using-sagemath-as-a-python-library)

Answer (score 2):

The sagemath package on PyPI, which you get by running

```sh
python -m pip install sagemath
```

does not install Sage, it only allows to check whether
Sage is installed.

It seems you are working on Windows and you installed
Sage using the Sage-Windows installer.

The command

```py
import sage.cubegroup
```

will work only if you use Sage's Python.

If you are using Python via some integrated development environment
such as PyCharm, you need to set it up to use Sage's Python.
See instructions in Iguananaut's answer to:

- [Ask Sage question 39742: Make PyCharm recognise the Sage Python interpreter on Windows](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/39742)

Comment: I trid c:/SageMath9.2/runtime/bin/python3.7m.exe, but I got the following error.
    `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sage'`.

I tested both
    `import sage.cubegroup;`
and
    `import sagemath.cubegroup;`.

I also tried to install the modules as
    `python3.7m -m pip install sage`,

but I got the following error.
    `No module named pip`.

**Why Sage's python cannot find sage??**

Comment: Btw, I did it on C:\SageMath9.2\runtime\bin\bash.exe.

Comment: I agree with @nemy. The instructions from Iguananaut's answer does not work for SageMath 9.2, installed with Windows binaries from http://www-ftp.lip6.fr/pub/math/sagemath/index.html